# Getting array index by watching its objects

Tags: angularjs

I use the code below to watch objects in an array. This works fine, however I'm not able to know the index of the object in the array (`i` below). Is this possible?

```
        scope.vars.forEach(function(elem,i){
            scope.$watch('vars['+i+']', function(newValue, oldValue) {

                // need to access i when the object is changed

            });
        });
```

Comment: There is no reason you can't access `i` in the `$watch` callback

Comment: how? it's not in `newValue`

Comment: No... it is simply `i` .. the same way you already used it

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Why is i available?

Comment: Well why shouldn't it be?

Comment: What about `$scope.$watchCollection('vars', function(newVars, oldVars) {})`?